# Will I get the latest state value in this case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to know whether my `onAdd` function in `<NewItemButton>` will get the latest value of `text` state.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  NewItemFormContainer,
  NewItemInput,
  NewItemButton
} from "./styles";

type NewItemFormProps = {
  onAdd(text: string): void
}

const NewItemForm = (props: NewItemFormProps) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  return (
    <NewItemFormContainer>
      <NewItemInput 
        value={text}
        onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
      />
      <NewItemButton onClick={() => props.onAdd(text)}>
        Create
      </NewItemButton>
    </NewItemFormContainer>
  );
}

export default NewItemForm;
```

If it does not get the latest value, what other ways can you suggest me? One that comes to my mind to use Refs (`forwardRef`) and send it directly to the html input element and then call `props.onAdd` with the current value. But the thing is that I am using `styled-components` and my `NewItemInput` looks like this

```
export const NewItemInput = styled.input`
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: #091e4240 0px 1px 0px 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  background: #484747;
  color: #f1f1f1;
`
```

So how will do that?

Comment: Well, yes. Every time the `text` state changes, so will everything in the `return` block. Are you seeing different results?

Comment: Yes, `() => props.onAdd(text)` will pass the current `text` state value to the callback. Is there an issue you are really trying to ask about? Something not working somewhere as expected?